# shorten Google Analytics code

Tags: google-analytics

Can the following line in Google Analytics code:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

be shortened to

```
ga.src = '//stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

?

The full script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a `Protocol Relative URL` and using one to shorten the Google Analytics code can cause some problems with IE6.

From Paul Irish @ Google on using [Protocol-Relative URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/):

> There is an edgecase bug in IE6 that causes a dialog to blow up… under some security settings from the non-‘ssl’ subdomain. So feel free to take 40 bytes off your GA snippet if you don’t care about IE6.. otherwise you’re gonna need that ternary operator. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do so it won't work if you load this file using the `file:` protocol to test your server for example. Besides that small problem it should work just fine.